# Нужно сделать задержку (таймер) к функциям на Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, таймер, python-3.7

Желаю сделать программу с определенными функциями на Python 3.7, которые будут выполняться с прошедшим временем. Пытался изучить библиотеки Tkinter и Time, но должной информации не нашел. Прошу помочь, *нужен простенький таймер на каждую функцию*.

Comment: `from threading import Timer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример импортировать модуль `time` и вызвать из него функцию `sleep`

```
import time
time.sleep(10)
```